# Kick/disconnect someone from voice chat in discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to know how to kick/disconnect someone from the voice channel the user is in, or a specific channel. I learned how to kick someone and here is my code:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../config.json');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  const member = message.mentions.users.first();
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS'))
    return message.reply(
      'NO tiene permiso para este comando mijo, ojo con ratismos inadecuados',
    );
  if (member) {
    const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
    memberTarget.kick();
    message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> pa juera de esta monda`);
  } else {
    message.channel.send('aja y a quien? a ti q?');
  }
};

module.exports.help = {
  name: 'kick',
};
```

I tried using `memberTarget.voicechat.disconnect()` instead of `memberTarget.kick()` and other codes. I tried from Discord.js.org but I don't get to do that, so I would be highly thankful if anyone could help me with this!

Comment: To send code, enclose it in 3 backticks on each side (`), or indent each line by 4 spaces. I'll send an edit to the review queue and hopefully it's approved so you can see it. -- EDIT: The edit queue for this is full, so I can't. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [`memberTarget.kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick) kicks someone from the server, [`memberTarget.voice.kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=kick) kicks someone from the voice channel. You could also get the first mentioned member using `message.mentions.members.first()`.

If you use [`mentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) instead of `mentions.users` you don't need to get the member from the user id.

Also, `memberTarget.kick()` will return a promise, so you should only send the message when it's resolved and handle rejections if there are any (using `catch()`).

See the code below:

```js
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  const memberTarget = message.mentions.members.first();

  if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS'))
    return message.reply(
      'NO tiene permiso para este comando mijo, ojo con ratismos inadecuados',
    );

  if (!memberTarget)
    return message.channel.send('aja y a quien? a ti q?');

  if (!memberTarget.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(`${memberTarget} no está en chat de voz`);

  memberTarget.voice
    .kick()
    .then((member) => message.channel.send(`${member} pa juera de esta monda`))
    .catch(console.error);
};
```

If you want to be able to mention more than one member you can iterate over `message.mentions.members` using the [`.each()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=each) method:

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS'))
  return message.reply(
    'NO tiene permiso para este comando mijo, ojo con ratismos inadecuados',
  );

if (!message.mentions.members.size) {
  return message.channel.send('aja y a quien? a ti q?');
}

message.mentions.members.each((memberTarget) => {
  if (!memberTarget.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(`${memberTarget} no está en chat de voz`);

  memberTarget.voice
    .kick()
    .then((member) =>
      message.channel.send(`${member} pa juera de esta monda`),
    )
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

[image]

If you want to add a counter, you need to wait until the bot tried to kick out every mentioned member. You can use `await Promise.all` to wait for all of them to finish and instead of `mentions.members.each` you need to use `mentions.members.map` which will return a new promise for each member:

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS'))
  return message.reply(
    'NO tiene permiso para este comando mijo, ojo con ratismos inadecuados',
  );

if (!message.mentions.members.size) {
  return message.channel.send('aja y a quien? a ti q?');
}

const counters = { notInVoiceChannel: 0, kicked: 0, error: 0 };

await Promise.all(
  message.mentions.members.map(async (memberTarget) => {
    if (!memberTarget.voice.channel) {
      return (counters.notInVoiceChannel += 1);
    }
    try {
      memberTarget.voice.kick();
      counters.kicked += 1;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      counters.error += 1;
    }
  }),
);

return message.channel.send(
  `**Kicked out:** ${counters.kicked}\n**Not in a voice channel:** ${counters.notInVoiceChannel}\n**Errors:** ${counters.error}`,
);
```

[image]

Comment: nice explaniation got it! now i have another issue, i want to kick 3 or 4 or 5 in a row from the voice channel, by calling !kick user 1 user2 user 3.... user n, and that would be my last question if u could :) ty a lot man!

Comment: I've updated the code so you can mention more than one member. Not sure if I can understand how you want to use that counter.

Comment: perfect, nasty that was what i was asking for! about the counter, i want to then the bot to say "total: 3 kicked " cause i mentioned 3, if u could also add the fact that if they are not in voice so they will be not be in total, in your example would say, total: 1 kicked, i hope i can be understood! ty a lot man ure big! peace

Comment: sure already did! than you!! thats all i needeed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the [VoiceState](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) part of the documentation and use the [VoiceState#kick](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=kick) method.

```
const member = message.mentions.users.first();
if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('NO tiene permiso para este comando mijo, ojo con ratismos inadecuados');
if(member){
    const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id)
    if(memberTarget.voice){
        memberTarget.voice.kick();
        message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> pa juera de esta monda`)
    }
}else {
    message.channel.send('aja y a quien? a ti q?');
}
```

Comment: ty a lot! worked perfectly!, know i have a question, what if i wanted to kick 2 or 3 mentions in a row? like i do !kick -user1 -user2 - user3 and something that counts the mentions i do